# How to align figure with subsection?

Tags: graphics, positioning, lncs, placeins

I have placed numerous figures beneath subsections, but there is a one page gap between the subsection title and the actual figure.

Does anyone know how to resolve this placement issue?

An MWE of the issue is outlined as folows, and these are the images being used http://picpaste.com/GesturePhysio_ProcessThreadSummary-J3gCQ99g.png, http://picpaste.com/gui_test_1-h3zNWpHU.png  , http://picpaste.com/gui_test_2-vZVQP6KV.png :

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% file typeinst.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This is the LaTeX source for the instructions to authors using
% the LaTeX document class 'llncs.cls' for contributions to
% the Lecture Notes in Computer Sciences series.
% http://www.springer.com/lncs       Springer Heidelberg 2006/05/04
%
% It may be used as a template for your own input - copy it
% to a new file with a new name and use it as the basis
% for your article.
%
% NB: the document class 'llncs' has its own and detailed documentation, see
% ftp://ftp.springer.de/data/pubftp/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncsdoc.pdf
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}


\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=C,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }



\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter  % start of an individual contribution

\title{Final Year Minor Dissertation}







\maketitle









\section{Appendices}
\label{sec:Appendecies}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}


\subsection{Performance and Profiling}

\FloatBarrier

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Sample of Process profiling  \cite{Visua8:online}}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{GesturePhysio_ProcessThreadSummary}
\end{figure}

\FloatBarrier



\subsection{GUI Tests}



\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{GUI Test - ROM View \cite{Visua8:online}}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{gui_test_1}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{GUI Test - Login View \cite{Visua8:online}}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{gui_test_2}
\end{figure}

\FloatBarrier


\end{document}
```

This is the position of the figure, with a one page gap between the subsection heading and the actual figure. I need to place the figure near to the subsection heading:

[image: figure position]

Comment: How big is the actual figure? Use `\fbox{\includegraphics[..]{...}}` and see whether the box just surrounds the image, or includes a large amount of whitespace around it.

Comment: Tried that on both images, that doesn't seem to be the issue as the bound is the same size as the visible image. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the community with code in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates this behaviour? We want to copy-and-paste-and-compile the code and it should duplicate the behaviour you're experiencing. It'll help us get to the bottom of this much quicker.

Comment: @Werner Okay just added an MWE of the issue, it compiles and links to images are in the question above ^^

Comment: Can you reproduce with a standard class or provide a link for this one, if it is required? It is not on CTAN or in TeX Live.